# CSS slider with link to pop up video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm trying to create a link to a pop up video in my css slider. I cant get the link to work. It seems like a simple task but its just not acting as a link. Any advice would be really appreciated

Here is my code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div style="width:100%; class="container-fluid">
     
         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>      
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>

    </ol>
    
     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <ul class="carousel-inner">
    <li class="item active">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yiif8r_U120" target="blank" 
    allowfullscreen controls>
      <img src="images/video_slider_button.jpg" alt="Video" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="images/test_slider.jpg" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="images/test_slider.jpg" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="images/toast_slider.jpg" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="images/test_slider.jpg" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="images/test_slider.jpg" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be an issue with an un-closed tag, here's some working code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div style="width:100%;" class="container-fluid">
     
         <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>      
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>

    </ol>
    
     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <ul class="carousel-inner">
    <li class="item active">
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yiif8r_U120" target="blank" 
    allowfullscreen controls>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Video Slide" alt="Video" style="width:100%;">
    </a>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide1" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide2" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide3" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide4" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=Slide5" alt="Test" style="width:100%;">
    </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

The issue I saw was that you never closed the quote for your div container, eg:

`<div style="width:100%; class="container-fluid">`
Should have been:
`<div style="width:100%;" class="container-fluid">`

Comment: Hi Zack.I added the quote marks but the video link still doesn't work. Any ideas what would make it work. Any help would be really appreciated. thanks

Comment: Try the code I posted, the link seems to work fine there? See the code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzfL6moz/) (StackOverflow won't let the link work in their embedded code tool)

Comment: And here's a [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/4yLQedD9) to show the differences between my code and yours

Comment: Hi Zack. Thanks so much for your answer but I added your code and its still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Post your file on jsfiddle or something and link it

Comment: hi Zack can i send you an email with a link please

Comment: Hi Zack I can't chat yet - I've just joined and need a higher reputation